# Drupal 6: Zencoder and S3 Access Issues

Tags: drupal, video, amazon-s3

My 2 fundamental problems are getting zencoder to save converted videos to my s3 bucket and getting drupal to access s3 correctly . I set up zencoder, s3 and all the other video modules mentioned on every "set up s3 and zencoder in drupal" tutorial you can find on the web and did all the required configuration but still cannot resolve the issues I'm having.

When a video is uploaded on my site, it is saved into both my dev.myurl.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/ folder and the sites/default/files/videos/original folder in my s3 bucket, transcoded to mp4 then 5 thumbnails are saved in the proper folder in my s3 bucket but the converted video is sent to zencoder's own temporary location and not the sites/default/files/videos/converted folder its supposed to make in my s3 bucket. When I try to play the video, it says "This video is currently being processed. Please wait.". When I go to edit video and play it from there, it plays it from my dev.myurl.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/ folder. The thumbnails in s3 are not being used either and I'm stuck with the default.

I know this may seem like a common problem that could be solved by reading other threads but I've been reading them all week and to little avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it this morning. It was an issue with the video presets table in the database that was resolved by reinstalling the video module. I was under the impression that the encoding and storage of videos was not working on my site because Zencoder or S3 were not set up properly and that the error was occurring outside of drupal, but it turned out the conversion presets in video configuration were never carrying over due to a missing table in the database. Reinstalling recreates the tables thus eliminating the database issues.